# Can ImageMagick be run portably off a USB flash drive?

Tags: imagemagick, portable-apps

I want to save ImageMagick to a USB flash drive so I can use it on multiple Windows computers, similar to PortableApps.

Can ImageMagick be configured to run portably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can download portable `.zip` versions of ImageMagick on their [official download page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).**

[image: Portable downloads for ImageMagick]

The default version of ImageMagick should not be run off a USB flash drive. When run, the software stores settings as Registry entries on the local PC.

I recommend the portable `x64` version for most users. If compatibility with legacy 32-bit PCs is a concern, use the `x86` version instead.